# Using another word instead of "in other words" in a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, vocabulary, sentence-usage

Is there any other form to use instead of **in other words** in this sentence?

> this toy provides children to learn how to use their ability **in other words**, children can learn new things from the toy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

> Essentially, That is to say, i.e., namely.

Also, I'd recommend starting a new sentence, like so:

> This toy **helps** children to learn how to use their ability. That is to say (or other option), children can learn new things from the toy.